# PubSub Python Library version 2.18.4 on Raspberry Pi creates error GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found

Tags: glibc, grpcio

When trying to run/install Google Python PubSub client on Raspberry Pi Debian Bullseye (version 11) released 2023-05-03, on trying to import the library I get a runtime error saying GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found specifically in libstdc.so.6.

It seems this library is not yet updated and grpcio 1.58 does not yet support raspberian.
To solve, I reverted Google Pubsub to version 2.18.1, grpcio and grpcio-status to version 1.56.2 which fixed the problem. Others facing the same issue will need to do the same.

Comment: I have this issue too. I have raised it here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/34888

Comment: I note that I don't have this issue with python 3.9